# Como obter somente os registros não duplicados com pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Como faria pra pegar somente as linhas não duplicadas de um dataframe? Sem os ser registros únicos, por isso `df.unique()` não caberia aqui. Só os que existem 1 mesmo.
Tentei dessa forma, mas não sei se é o correto.

```
df2 = DF
df2.drop_duplicates('userId', keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Assim usaria o `df2` onde todos os que não estão duplicados sobrariam. Essa forma está correta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quase.

`df2 = DF` não cria uma cópia de `DF`, só dá mais um nome pra ele.

Quando você dá `drop_duplicates(..., inplace=True)` as modificações acontecem direto no dataframe (i.e. seu data frame perde as duplicatas). Do jeito que você fez, as duplicatas sairiam de `DF`, além de `df2` (por que na verdade eles são a mesma coisa).

O correto seria simplesmente:

```
df2 = DF.drop_duplicates('userId', keep=False)
```

Isso cria uma cópia de DF sem dados que tenham duplicatas e coloca em df2.

Comment: O correto seria seria sem o `(..., inplace=True)` ?

Comment: Exato, e de preferência sem o `df2 = DF` no começo também, que perde o uso. O `inplace=True` faz a operação acontecer direto no dataframe em que é chamado, enquanto que sem ele a operação é feita em uma cópia, que é retornada pela função depois.